# Is @font-face render blocking?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, web-performance

Is @font-face render blocking? In other words, if I use @font-face at the top of my style sheet, do my fonts load asynchronously or will the browser wait to load the rest of my styles until *after* the fonts have loaded?

Thank you kindly everyone!

Comment: are you talking about google font or self-hosted font?

Comment: @mrhossen I mean a self-hosted font. Although, can't a typeface from the Google Fonts directory also be self-hosted?

Comment: This should be easy enough to test on your own without needing help from SO, by writing a test file that has an @font-face for a Chinese or Japanese font, with more styles after, and loading it with artificially throttled bandwidth settings to simulate a slow connection.